# How to upload a pandas Dataframe containing pd.Period to a database using to_sql()

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to upload a DataFrame to SQL Server using `to_sql`.

Since the data I am working with contains a timestamp column spanning ca 1900 to 8999 I used the "out of bounds"-workaround [described here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-oob). In short the workaround is to use [pandas.Period](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.html).

This works as expected and the DataFrame now contains the correct dates encoded es `Period`s.

Here is an excerpt of  `df.dtypes`

```
measureDate       period[S]
```

When I try uploading the DataFrame like this

```
df.to_sql(db_table, engine, if_exists='append', chunksize=500000)
```

the upload fails with this error:

```
ValueError: cannot infer type for <class 'NoneType'>
```

When I give it the correct datatype (or: the datatype I think is the correct one)

```
dt_dict = {'measureDate':sqlalchemy.DateTime}
df.to_sql(db_table, engine, if_exists='append', chunksize=500001,dtype=dt_dict)
```

I get this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=2 param-type=Period', 'HY105')
```

What is the correct way to upload `Period`s as a SQL Server datetime column?

Comment: Can you convert the `measureDate` column to a string representation (e.g., `'1066-10-14 08:15:12'` before calling `to_sql()`?

Comment: I could, but wouldn't that upload a string to the database, not a datetime?

Comment: If you're inserting into an existing table (`if_exists='append'`) and the corresponding column is a datetime type then the database engine will probably do the conversion from string for you.

Comment: Saving it as pythons datetime (so pandas shows it as `object` and uploading it to a sql server `datetime`-column indeed worked, thanks!